# Create Boolean function to display an image in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement, woocommerce, metadata

I'm looking to create a function which would allow me to display an image thanks to a custom field which would be with a boolean value "true" or "false" and which would use the slug name of the product, but being only a beginner j I have some difficulty implementing it, could you help me!

Here is my current code:

```
function custom_title_field() {
    global $product;
    $product = get_post( $post_id );
    $slug = $product->post_name;
    // Get the field name of InputText1
    $label = get_post_meta($product, 'title', true);
    if( is_product( $post_id ) ){
        return '<h1 class="display-3"><img class="" src="'. get_template_directory_uri() .'/inc/assets/img/shop/hero/'.$slug.'_title.svg" alt="Six Stars" data-inject-svg /></h1>';
    }
}
```

and this code put in my single-product.php file :

```
<?php
  // get the post ID outside the Loop
  $post_id = get_queried_object_id();
  // print the <img>
  echo custom_title_field( $post_id );
?>
```

In this code, the image is displayed well but when there is no image to display, the code displays an empty wh1> <img ....> elements

I'm not sure if my explanation is clear and understandable, so I created a descriptive image for it!

[image]

Let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
function custom_title_field( $post_id ) {
    if( is_product( $post_id ) && get_post_meta( $post_id, 'title', true ) ){
        $post = get_post( $post_id );
        $slug = $post->post_name;

        return '<h1 class="display-3"><img class="" src="'. get_template_directory_uri() .'/inc/assets/img/shop/hero/'.$slug.'_title.svg" alt="Six Stars" data-inject-svg /></h1>';
    }
}
```

For your template `single-product.php`:

```
<?php echo custom_title_field( get_the_id() ); ?>
```

It should solve your problem

Comment: No sorry, your code and solution don't work fine!

It's very strange because only the first product that I visit display the image, the others that I list don't display the image and the result for the empty code "<h1 class="display-3"><img class=""... stay the same!

Comment: Thank you , it work fine for all products now but when I put false in my custom field and if image exist, the image is displayed!

Comment: @GilbertOOl Sorry but if `get_post_meta( $post_id, 'title', true )` is `false`, empty or doesn't exist, nothing is returned by the function…

Comment: Ok thanks, and lot of thanks for your time to help